# How to run multiple scripts/multiple scenarios together(in a sigle execution) in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to execute the different workflows(suchlike., scenario-1; scenario-2; scenario-3; scenario-4......scenario-n) in a single execution with different threads.

Answer (score 0):

User multiple thread groups for the scenerio's and change each thread groups configuration to have different threads.

Update:-
You can use [JMeter Ant](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter) Task or [JMeter Maven Plugin](http://jmeter.lazerycode.com/) to run tests execution. Both can execute tasks/jmx in parallel.

Comment: Ya, it is okay for multiple users by using thread groups. But, how for multiple projects/multiple Testplan/scenarios we can run/execute in a single execution. Please suggest.

Comment: Please check the update,if it fits your requirements.